# Assembly DLL management in .Net

Tags: .net, dll

What is the safest way to make sure IIS picks up changes to a recompiled DLL?
1. Just copy the DLL in the /bin folder?
2. Clear the application cache?
3. Restart IIS?
4. Reboot the server?
Note: I'm pretty sure options 3 & 4 would work, but they might be a tad drastic in a production environment ;-)

Comment: I think, to be absolutely sure, you should build a new server from scratch, with new hardware, and then copy the DLL to the /bin folder. :) This method should be called "Nuke the site from orbit, it's the only way to be sure!"

Answer (score 6):

Copying the DLL into the \bin ought to recycle the worker process.  If that doesn't work then the best thing to do is to recycle the AppPool.  When you recycle your AppPool this will unload your website's AppDomain. When a new AppDomain is created it will load the new version of your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

touch Web.config file?

Comment: Are you sure or is it just a guess?

Comment: This will just trigger what "Andrew Hare" wrote about.

Comment: I'm sure, the question mark just means it's not a cleanest solution. But it is a good solution if you want to restart your Web app. even without changing any DLLs.